# Admob and ListActivity

Tags: android, layout, admob, listactivity

I have asked this question before but didn't get a "good enough" answer.

My problem basically is that I can't get Admob to show correctly in a ListActivity.

My layout looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/se.javalia.myDrinks"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/main_no_items" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
            myapp:keywords="drink alcohol wiskey rum soda" myapp:refreshInterval="300" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem right now is that if I change the layout_hight to fill_parent or attempt a value larger than 150 px the ad wont show. With a layout_hight of 150 or less it shows nicely. The goal is to get the list to fill the screen after the ad has taken its place.

Any suggestions? I'm quite lost about how to solve this.

I will update the question if the answer didn't get all the way so please check for updates.

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 1):

Use one RelativeLayout as the outer wrapper and set your listview to parent top and your adview to parent bottom.

Comment: I have updated the xml in the question but not I don't se the ad. It looks like there are room reserved in the layout but no ad.

Comment: Use the test mode on the emulator, or your device to make sure an ad is always returned.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was very difficult to find answers in internet. But i had luck, and I found an answer that worked for me.

Please remove in your code <strike>android:layout_height="wrap_content"</strike> and add these two new lines into your `Listview`

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Your Listview code should look like this

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

I hope that works for you.